# Delete realm objects from various classes in TableView cause "Can only delete an object from the Realm it belongs to." exception

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm, realm-list

i have a tableView filled with Realm array, the list array is combined from 3 other Realm results array as you can see in the below code. Now I want to implement the delete action for each cell. But the app returned these exceptions, so please anyone can help me to solve this?. Thank you guys very much.

```
class BookmarksVC: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

var articleList: Results<DynamicObject>!
var documentList: Results<DynamicObject>!
var itArticleList: Results<DynamicObject>!
var list = [Any]()
var article: Any!
var searchBar:UISearchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 20))

func loadDataAndUpdateUI() {
    articleList = realm.dynamicObjects(NewsArticle.className())
    documentList = realm.dynamicObjects(Documents.className())
    itArticleList = realm.dynamicObjects(ITNewsArticle.className())
    for article in articleList {
        list.append(article)
    }
    for document in documentList {
        list.append(document)
    }
    for itArticle in itArticleList{
        list.append(itArticle)
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    print(list.count)
    return list.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    article = list[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bookmarkCell", for: indexPath) as! BookmarkCell
    cell.configureCell(article:article)
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete") { (deleteAction, indexPath) -> Void in

        //Deletion will go here
        let itemToBeDeleted = self.list[indexPath.row]
        try! realm.write {
            realm.delete(itemToBeDeleted as! Object)
        }
    }
    return [deleteAction]
}
```

[image: Exception:]

I would also attach code for creating these objects:

```
 func saveFavoriteArticle() {
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(bookmarkItem!)
    }
    print(realm.dynamicObjects(NewsArticle.className()))
}
//Same code for 2 remaining objects
```

Comment: Could you show the code around creating those `realm` instances?

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi I've just added the creating instance code, pls checkout. Thanks.

Comment: I meant is how do you create the `realm` instances. Not saving each object. Because this error says you attempt to save the objects those already are stored another realm file. Can you show the code around instantiating `realm` instances? Like `let realm = try! Realm(...)`